# What are the properties of this linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, generating-functions

Suppose $f(x)$ is a function which satisfies the following condition:

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty G(2k)\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$

Where the generating function $G(x)$ is a "natural" or "discrete-analytic" function in the sense it is equal to its Newton series expansion:

$$G(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{x}k \Delta^k G\left (0\right)$$

The function $f(x)$ is evidently even.
Now the operator $U$ on $f(x)$ is defined as follows:

$$Uf(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty G(2k+1)\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

It is evident that this operator is linear. It transforms an even function to a similarly-looking odd one. Yet it is not defined for polynomials because they do not satisfy the first condition.

Given that the basis vectors of the standard Hilbert space of analytic functions are polynomials, so $U$ cannot be applied to the basis vectors, and I cannot construct the infinite matrix corresponding to this operator.

My questions are the following:

- Is it possible still find the matrix corresponding to the operator in the basis $e_n=x^n/n!$?
- At what conditions the operator transforms elementary functions to elementary ones?

Comment: Perhaps your question is this:  Can the operator, which is a priori only defined on certain even functions, be extended (continuously? uniquely? canonically?) to all (even? analytic?) functions?

Comment: @Goldstern I am interested in this particular operator. Since it is linear, it should have certain infinite matrix, such that multiplication by that matrix is equal to applying the operator. Finding the matrix would allow to generalize the operator.

Comment: Are you sure this "operator" is well-defined? If $G$ and $G'$ agree at every even number, they also agree at every odd number?

Comment: @Nik Weaver yes.This is how "discrete-analytic" functions behave.

Comment: @Anixx: are you using the term "discrete-analytic" in some nonstandard way?

Comment: @Nik Weaver  the definition is in the question.

Comment: @Nik Weaver Alternatively, one can require F(k)=G(2k) to be discrete-analytic, and then take F(k+1/2) in the definition of the operator. The result should be totally the same.